# Is possible to have OR logic on block visibility?

Tags: blocks, plugins

I am on D10.

I need to place several blocks on Block Layout having different visibility conditions: for example one of them should visible BOTH in the home page and in every article of the site.

I'd use therefore "Content Type" condition and "Request Path". However,I've realized that different condition plugins work with AND logic: if I check both, the block isn't visible in neither front page or articles.

Is possible somehow to specify that I want the conditions to work with OR logic?

I'd avoid to place every block several time, one for each condition, to avoid the cluttering of the block layout and the difficulties to maintain it in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the module [Block Visibility Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_visibility_groups), This module not only allows you to combine conditions with OR logic, but also makes them reusable, so you don't need to repeat the complex logic for each block if you have multiple blocks showing on the same pages.